# Arithmetic series and sequence + geometric sequence

Tags: calculus

I have a math test tomorrow and for the review, there are a few questions I don't know how to complete. Here they are:

> Determine the tenth term of the arithmetic sequence in which the first
>   term is 5 and the fourth term is 17.

I might have solved it, this is my work.

17 = 5 + 3d
d = 4

t10 = 5 + 4(10-1)
t10 = 41

> The sum of the first 12 terms of an arithmetic series is 186, and the
>   20th term is 83. What is the sum of the first 40 terms?

Don't know where to start.

> In a geometric sequence, the third term is 54 and the sixth term is
>   -1458. Determine the values of t1 (Term 1) and r, and list the first three terms of the sequence.

Don't know how to start with this one either.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on a problem.  What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?  Please edit your post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

1. The information you have for the arithmetic sequence is
   $$
   a_1 = 5 \\
   a_4 = 17 \\
   a_n = a_0 + n k \quad (*)
   $$
   So you can infer $a_0$ and $k$ from the two known values, they deliver two equations 
   $$
   a_1 = a_0 + k \cdot 1 = 5 \\
   a_4 = a_0 + k \cdot 4 = 17
   $$
   which you can solve, and then calculate $a_{10}$ via equation $(*)$.
2. The sum of the first $N$ sequence elements (starting at index $1$) would be:
   $$
   S_N 
   = \sum_{n=1}^N a_n
   = \sum_{n=1}^N a_0 + n k
   = a_0 \left(\sum_{n=1}^N 1 \right) + k \sum_{n=1}^N n 
   = N a_0 + k \frac{N(N+1)}{2} \quad (**)
   $$
   Your information leads to the equations
   $$
   S_{12} = 186 = 12 a_0 + k \frac{12 (12+1)}{2} \\
   a_{20} = a_0 + k \cdot 20 = 83
   $$
   Then use $(**)$ to evaluate $S_{40}$.
3. For the geometric sequence, you should start with thinking about the relation between the sequence values, something like equation $(*)$, and then again make use of the given values to come up with the general sequence and then evaluate it for the wanted sequence value.

Answer (score 0):

Arithmetic sequence: To get to the next term add a certain constant

Geometric sequence: To get to the next term multiply by a certain constant

In an arithmetic sequence  if we take $a_n$ to represent the $n$th term, then the graph will be linear with the common difference of $a_{n}-a_{n-1}=\frac{a_{n}-a_{n-1}}{(n)-(n-1)}$ as the slope.

In a geometric sequence, the closed form of $a_n$ is an exponential with that constant you need to get from $a_n$ to $a_{n+1}$ as $r$. $a_n=a_1(r)^{n-1}$. This results from the constant need of multiplying by $r$ and the fact that $a_1$ is when $n=1$.

Concerning the first and second problem, find the slope using $n$ as your independent variable (x-axis) and $a_n$ as your dependent variable (y axis). Remember slope is the change of your dependent variable of your independent variable. Then use the points to solve for your a_n-intercept.

For the third one use the points to solve the constants in the exponential equation.

Also for one of these problems (the second) , it can do you good to know:

$$1+2+3+....+(n-2)+(n-1)+n$$

because $1,2,3,4,5,..n$ Is arithmetic (linear) the average from $1$ to $n$ is $\frac{n+1}{2}$. Multiply by $n$ numbers and get the sum because average=sum/#numbers. Thus,

$$1+2+3+4.....(n-3)+(n-2)+(n-1)+n=\frac{n+1}{2}•n$$

Answer (score 0):

first question answer:
first term of arithmetic progressions is 5
Then we get, 5+(3×d)=17 
            or,d=(17-5)÷3
                =4 
Where d is common difference of arithmetic progressions.
10th term of arithmetic progressions is 5+(9×4)=5+36=41.

Second answer:
Let,First term of the arithmetic progressions is =a.
Common difference of the arithmetic progressions is=d.
Then we get,a+(19×d)=83.....(1)
From the question we get,the sum of the first 12th terms is 186.
Then we get, (12÷2){(2×a)+(11×d)}=186
                        or,6×{2a+11d}=186
                        or,12a+66d=186.......(2)
Multiply (-12) in the question no.(1)
We get,-12a-228d=-996 ......(3)
Add by the the equations no. (2) and (3),we get,
               -162d=-810
              or,d=5
Put the value of  d in the equation no. (1). Then we get the value of a=-12.
The sum of the first 40th terms of the arithmetic progression is,
(40÷2){(2×a)+(40-1)d}=20×{2a+39d}=20×{-24+195} [put the value of the a and d]
=3420.